# Adding button with external URL to jenkins

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to add to build page (jenkins/view/job/job_name/build_no)/ external button that will redirect user to external report on other machine. I've got external tool with test reports, so I want only to allow user to click on jenkins build page, redirect him and show test result.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AnchorChain plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnchorChain+plugin) allows you to do this dynamically by creating a text file as part of your build.